# Would "has" or "have" be correct here?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

I was looking over another person's written article online. When leaving a suggestion in favor of the second of the two sentences below, I was told that the first is actually correct.

The former is the sentence that was there to start with; the sentence below it is the recommendation of mine that was turned down:

"A number of brutal attacks and robberies **has** left many outsiders disillusioned with the culture."

"A number of brutal attacks and robberies have left many outsiders disillusioned with the culture."

I have very rarely, if ever, seen the first of the two in writing. Is it a mere singularity of AP style?

Comment: As noted in the answers, "has" refers to "a number". Technically the original is correct, but you can see what arguments arise. In this case, as an editor, I'd be targeting "a number", as I find it a sloppy term anyway. "**Several** brutal attacks and robberies have …"

Answer (score 1):

"Has" in this case is describing the word "number" (which is singular).  "Have" would be correct if the sentence started off with "Brutal attacks and robberies...have...".

"The number **has** left many people disillusioned."

"The robberies **have** left many people disillusioned."

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Zabari. I have had a feeling, however, that the rule changes depending on whether the number is definite or indefinite.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good case of where purported "rules" are either pedantic or overtaken by common usage.  The use of have after "a number" or "the number" is both widespread and unexceptional: *A number of people have been injured in the fire*. is perfectly okay, for example, while "has" and other singular forms can look stilted and a little precious.

In the OP's sample sentence, it is "doubly" he case that ***have*** is both common usage and totally acceptable, since the subject is A and B. To say "A number of brutal attacks and robberies have left many outsiders disillusioned ..." not only sounds and looks better, it doesn't offend logic.